# How to uninstall WAMP service on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-services

I can't uninstall `wamp apache` service from the `services` list

I have modified the `uninstall_services` file of `wamp` to look like:

```
NET STOP wampapache
.\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\httpd.exe -k uninstall -n 'wamp apache cow'
```

i had a stupid ideea to write 3 words for the service name and now i can't delete this service

any ideas?

[image: image here]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete service you can try in command promt

```
sc delete <SERVICE_NAME>
```